# SAS Error - WARNING: Variable gender has already been defined as numeric

Tags: sas

[I get these errors with my code] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6K3R.png)

I am trying to run step 3, but to no avail.  Basically, I am trying to run a model selection procedure but I get stuck on this step.  I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Happy to share my code.

I am not sure how to proceed or if anyone has any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Post code and text as actual text, not photographs.  Don't show error messages out of context.  The error is clear.  You are trying to treat the variable as if was character by using a character format with it.  So it warned you and then looked for a numeric format with the same name, but it could not find it.  Fix the step that created the variable. Or change the code to work with the numeric variable you have.